# Change name of the folder with mozilla thunderbird extension

Tags: javascript, mozilla, thunderbird-addon

I'm not experienced in creating ff/thunderbird extensions, but I have to modify one open source addon, and the easiest way to reach what I want is to change name of one folder. My question is: how to do it, having path and name of the folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder is created by the TB-extension:
Open the .js-file and search for the folders name (ctrl+f). In this example it's "FolderName".

If there is something like `var folder = FileUtils.getDir("ProfD", ["FolderName"], true);` you can replace `FolderName` with the new name.

If you want to know how to create a folder, check [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Creating_Folders).